# WPF Dispatcher Invoking with a Progress Bar

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, dispatcher

I've been trying to learn how to use Dispatches in Windows Presentation Foundation for like 4 hours now and there's a problem I can't seem to solve at all no matter how much Googling I do.

I've got this simple program to work out the percentage of the way I'm through a set time frame, e.g. 19% of the way from 5th January to 31st March.

No matter what I try, I've tried writing a DayChangeNotification class but that kept giving me issues, then tried using a Nuget package to setup a scheduling task for window but decided that was cutting corners so I went back to a slightly modified 'MidnightNotifier' which I found on some stackoverflow, here's my code for the MainWindow -- I'm not 100% sure on how to work with events, coming from entirely synchronous linear game making so please be gentle :)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DateMeter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 6), EndDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 30); //Made a global for these as an attempt
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width - (50 * (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width / 2560)); //Don't know if this ratio
            Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - Height - (50 * (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height / 1440)); //code works yet.
            ProgressBar timeToDate = pbDate;
            pbDate.Value = ((DateTime.Now.Date - StartDate).TotalDays / (EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays);
            pbDate.Maximum = 1; //Value between 0-1 rather than 0-100

            MidnightNotifier.DayChanged += (o, e) => 
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate ()
                {
                    pbDate.Value = ((DateTime.Now.Date - StartDate).TotalDays / (EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays);
                });

            };
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my MidnightNotifier class,

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace DateMeter
{
    static class MidnightNotifier
    {
        private static readonly Timer timer;

        static MidnightNotifier()
        {
            timer = new Timer(GetSleepTime());
            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
            {
                OnDayChanged();
                timer.Interval = GetSleepTime();
            };
            timer.Start();

            SystemEvents.TimeChanged += OnSystemTimeChanged;
        }

        private static double GetSleepTime()
        {
            var midnightTonight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
            var differenceInMilliseconds = (midnightTonight - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
            return differenceInMilliseconds;
        }

        private static void OnDayChanged()
        {
            var handler = DayChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(null, null);
        }

        private static void OnSystemTimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = GetSleepTime();
        }

        public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> DayChanged;
    }
}
```

If you'd like any more info let me know, thanks for any help guys :)

Edit: My bad it completely slipped my mind, sorry guys

```
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DateMeter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="150" Width="150" WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ProgressToAngleConverter x:Key="ProgressConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}" x:Key="ProgressBarStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Fill="#969696"/>
                            <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Margin="5" Fill="#2B2B2B"/>
                            <local:Arc StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="#2ce64e" Margin="1">
                                <local:Arc.StartAngle>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ProgressConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </local:Arc.StartAngle>
                                <local:Arc.EndAngle>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ProgressConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </local:Arc.EndAngle>
                            </local:Arc>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, StringFormat={}{0:0.0%}}"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="24" FontWeight="Light"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border CornerRadius="90" BorderBrush="#2B2B2B" BorderThickness="4" Background="#838383">
        <Grid>
            <Viewbox>
                <ProgressBar Name="pbDate" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle}" 
                             Height="100" Width="100"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Here's my xaml for the MainWindow (only window I have)

The issue that keeps arising is the classic 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: Post XAML for your Window.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad @LordWilmore , it completely slipped my mind, there you go, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Please read [mcve] so that you understand what sort of code is required for a question like this. It is critical that you not include any code that is not _directly_ related to the problem, but that the code you post _is_ a 100% complete program. This means you need to put effort into writing a simplified version of what you're trying to do, which still reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." occurs in the `DayChanged` event handler, right? Take a look at this from MSDN:

> If a System.Timers.Timer is used in a WPF application, it is worth
>   noting that the System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread than
>   the user interface (UI) thread. In order to access objects on the user
>   interface (UI) thread, it is necessary to post the operation onto the
>   Dispatcher of the user interface (UI) thread using Invoke or
>   BeginInvoke. Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer as opposed to a
>   System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same
>   thread as the Dispatcher and a DispatcherPriority can be set on the
>   DispatcherTimer.

The above is from the [`DispatchTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer) documentation. Basically, if you use `DispatchTimer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer` then the event that gets raised from said timer will occur on the same thread as the UI, so the handlers will be able to interact with the UI freely, without having to call `Dispatcher.Invoke`.